# How to use JodaTime in google cloud endpoints in android studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify, endpoints

I am currently working google app engine using objectify, endpoints and datastore.I wanted to use jodatime to store date and time on datastore but I am unable to do that because of following exception:
**ISOChronology is not a registered @Subclass**

then I change my code

from :

```
static {
    ObjectifyService.register(Attendance.class);
}
```

To:

```
static {
  JodaTimeTranslators.add(factory());
  ObjectifyService.register(Attendance.class);
 }
```

**now it is giving me following error while deployment:**

Endpoints configuration not updated.  The app returned an error when the Google Cloud Endpoints server attempted to communicate with it.
Jun 17, 2016 5:57:59 PM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload checkEndpointsServingStatusResult
SEVERE: Endpoints configuration not updated.  The app returned an error when the Google Cloud Endpoints server attempted to communicate with it.

Now if I add JodaTimeTranslators.add(factory()) then IDE always give the same error and none of APIs works. But when I remove the line then other APIs except API targeted for this problem started working.

So please tell me how can I use jodatime with endpoints ?

Comment: Hi, you maybe could have a look at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/objectify-appengine/U9COBUVWnKQ

Comment: I asked there before I posted to stackoverflow. it did not help because probably its problem related to endpoints